# XmlRpc calls do not reach the MySql Server

Tags: c#, mysql, proxy, clickonce, xml-rpc

I have written a ClickOnce application in C# that needs to run on any pc behind any firewall, proxy settings or antivirus etc since my users are all over the country.

On 95% of my users the XmlRpc calls do reach the database server. Here are the things I have tried so far :

1. Used `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.GetProxy(url).ToString();` to get the correct proxy url.
2. Assigned the above found proxy to the XmlRpc proxy object.
3. Set the credentials for the XmlRpc object using `CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;`
4. Set `AllowAutoRedirect = true;` for the XmlRpc object
5. Set `KeepAlive = true;` for the proxy object
6. Set `Expect100Continue = false;` for the proxy object
7. I use the default timeout which is 100000 ms

On some problem pc's after starting Fiddler 2 the communication to the MySql database starts working. I'd rather not install Fiddler 2 on all problem pc's.

My question is what else can I do or check to make sure all XmlRpc calls reaches the MySql server. Is the above method of finding the proxy url 100% reliable ? Or can I replace the XmlRpc with a another 100% reliable communications method ?

I am using XmlRpc .Net 2.5.0 for communication and .Net 3.5 for my application.
The XmlRpc calls are normal http calls on port 80 as far as I understand.

Thx for any suggestions.

Comment: Maybe I should upgrade to XmlRpc .Net Version 3.0.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

If it works when you run fiddler I assume it's because the pc is then using Fiddlers proxy...

Taken from [fiddler2.com/documentation/KnowledgeBase/Proxy](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/KnowledgeBase/Proxy)
"After you start Fiddler, the program registers itself as the system proxy for Microsoft Windows Internet Services (WinInet), the HTTP layer used by Internet Explorer, Microsoft Office, and many other products."

Does your code assume that there is always a proxy? Have a look at WebProxy.GetProxy [which can be found at this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy.getproxy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: No, I have support for a direct internet connection without a proxy in a similar fashion as the link you provided. Thx.

Comment: Have you tried to use WebProxy.GetProxy to see if it is more reliable?

Comment: Can't remember, I have tried a lot of things a while ago, but I'll add it to the application and log the information and compare the proxy urls and take it from there. Thank you.